# Using '*' then declaring more variables in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

Teradata does not seem to like a statement of the following structure:

```
select
*,
1 as new_var_1,
2 as new_var_2,
3 as new_var_3
from
mylib.mytable
;
```

In other SQL flavours I have used though, this has not been an issue. Is there a way to get around this problem, or am I stuck with it?

Thanks

Comment: Alias the table with say t and use t.*

Comment: `select mytable.*, .... `

Comment: Specify all columns in your select.  `Select *` is evil.